# Null Exception with Array.FindIndex searching in a string array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Someone has chosen to mark this as duplicate, and though I can appreciate trying to clean up a question asking community, the I have examined the "duplicated" material in detail prior to posting my question. As indicated in my question below, I show the outputs of the issue in question, which has no nulls.

I have a method I create based on a user selecting a spinner value that looks like this:

```
    public void terrain_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        var ttype = string.Format("{0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
        Console.WriteLine(ttype);
        foreach (var item in Terrainstr) { Console.WriteLine(item); }
        var index = Array.FindIndex(Terrainstr, x => x.Contains(ttype));
```

As you can see, the string ttype is simply the selection the user makes with the spinner.

I have a string array Terrainstr that's initialized before OnCreate like this:

```
string[] Terrainstr = new string[10];
```

I populate it later with string fragments based on a number of user selections.

You'll notice I have Console.WriteLine commands in the method. My  (annotated) output when that method is used is:

```
Fast (ttype)
Stock (Terrainstr[0])
Slow 
Slow Sand 
Slow Sand Rocks Whoops 
Slow Sand Mud Rocks Whoops 
Slow Mud Rocks Whoops 
Slow Mud Rocks (Terrainstr[6])
```

I want to find which indeces of Terrainstr contain ttype. In this case, it wouldn't fit it at all. I get a null exception using the command shown here:

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(Terrainstr, x => x.Contains(ttype));
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 4):

Basically your array is of size 10 and you only have 8 elements in it (based on `Console.WriteLine` output) so the last two are `null`s.

`Array.FindIndex` doesn't check if the element is null or not and pass it to your lambda where you try to run `.Contains`. If it's null then you get a `NullReferenceExeception`.

Filter you array and only do the `FindIndex` on non-null elements.

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(Terrainstr, x => x != null && x.Contains(ttype));
```